# Remove arrow from BootStrap tags input

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How can I remove the arrow appear in frone of tags input as shown in image 
[image]

demo here: https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form.html

Comment: can you create an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I just noticed, when I remove all tags, it disappear

Comment: here is demo https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form.html

Comment: That arrow is created by `.tag:after` inside `custom.min.css`file. Simply remove that CSS style or override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the inspector / developer console on your browser you can see that the arrow is generated by:

```
.tag:after {
  content: " ";
  height: 30px;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left: 11px solid #1ABB9C
}
```

Inspector claims this is part of `custom.min.css` beginning at line 2,922.

This arrow was probably supposed to appear directly adjacent to the actual tag, but it looks like `position:relative` is missing from key elements as well as other aspects of `.tag` being re-defined throughout the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I see that on other page [here](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/general_elements.html), that the Daily active users '.tag' has the arrow that's been bothering you.

I suggest that you extend the .tag class and add the pseudo code for the arrow

```
ul{
   &.timeline{
       li{
          .tag{
              @extend .tag;
              &:after{
                  /* add code for arrow here */
              }
          }
       } 
   }
}
```

or

simply hide the tag by selecting a specific parent like this:

```
.tagsinput .tag:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is most quickest to implement. Thanks @rand0m